# Compiler error when using HAL functions for I2C communication

Tags: stm32, i2c, debugging, error

I am using the board STM32F3 and I am trying to establish I2C communication between the microcontroller and the accelerometer LSM303DLHC by using the HAL functions. This is the code:

```
uint8_t IC[4];

#define acc 0b0011001

IC[0] = 0x20;           // register adress

IC[1] = 0x87;          // data to write

HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, acc<<1, IC, 2, 10);
```

When I compile, I obtain the following errors:

```
error: #165: too few arguments in function call

error: #18: expected a ")"
```

I have no idea how to debug this code, can someone help me?

Comment: Look correct to me.

Comment: The error is probably not in the posted code. Include the code for the whole function where the compiler error appears, including all variable declarations and `#include`s. Smells like some stray `(` or semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler does not support binary literals. Change the define to hex or decimal.

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly that problem and now it is solved ;)